# Backup Centos Server on Personal Windows 7 Computer

Tags: backup, rsync

Using rsync or with a similar method, I would like to backup my dedicated Centos server (client websites specifically) on my personal Windows 7 computer every week. Is there an application (paid or not paid) that I can install on my Windows machine to SSH into my Linux server and schedule automatic backups?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of paying for something, you could always cron rsync to transfer stuff from your server to your personal machine. This site has some step-by-step instructions on accomplishing it: http://www.tux.org/~tbr/rsync/

Comment: I rather use an application/GUI interface - if one exists. Otherwise I will need to hire someone to do this.

Comment: @steeped You're on a site for professional systems administration. Being able to script, automate, and use the command line are basic skills that any pro admin should have. If you're unwilling to use a tool that doesn't have a GUI, you're not going to get very far in this profession.

Comment: @MDMarra I am a website developer, not a server admin. I don't ever plan on being a server admin. I would just like a way to back up my server.

Comment: Then this site probably isn't the right place to ask these questions. Maybe [webmasters.se] or [SU] might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

On sf.net, search for grsync or qtdsync, they are both CrossPlatform GUI interfaces to rsync.  Haven't tried them, but was tempted after recent problems with a rsync script.

Comment: Anyone involved in IT needs to know how to be able to carry their own luggage, web designers are not exempt.  Install cygwin and learn rsync.